# In Cell E10, enter a formula to find the Data limit of each customer

Tags: excel

In Cell E10, enter a formula to find the Data limit of each customer

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfK2B.png

Not really sure how to answer this question.

Comment: please add some more explanation on the question.

Answer (score -2):

=HLOOKUP(C10,$B$22:$E$24,2,False)

Comment: Could you explain further why this answers the question?